# Add/Continue a new subsection to an older section after it was ended [in toc]

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, page-numbering

I'm basically looking to not order things how they appear chronologically, page-wise.
Instead, if I have [subsection #1.3] after [section #n], add #1.3 to #1 instead of #n, for ToC reasons.

What I get when I use \tableofcontents:

```
1 SECTION ONE                                [page number, let's pick 1]
1.1 SUBSECTION                                 1
1.2 SUBSECTION                                1

2 SECTION TWO                                 1
2.1 SUBSECTION                                1

% then continue section 1, I can change the display number but
% it's still added to Section 2

2.2 SUBSECTION                                2
1.3 SUBSECTION                                2
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

```
1 SECTION ONE                                 1
1.1 SUBSECTION                                1
1.2 SUBSECTION                                1
1.3 SUBSECTION                                2 %note the difference in page

2 SECTION TWO                                 1
2.1 etc                                       2
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! May I ask why you want to do that? That is IMHO very unusual, not to say disturbing reading a paper ... Please register your account to be able to edit your question and more ...

Comment: I'm writing a type of wiki document for extended notetaking filtered by topic. I'm not using the "sections" for what they represent but would like to have a similar ordered, numbered structure in the ToC. Hypothetical: a "Technology" and "Biology" section, each subsection filtered under their topic so even though it's not organized I can easily find their respective page, and when adding something don't need to mess around with formatting. I already have quite a few groups so making a new document for every type would get tedious, this is the best I came up with next to doing it manually.